# Append xargs argument number as prefix

Tags: shell, xargs

I want to analyze the most frequentry occuring entries in (column of) a logfile. To write the detail results, I am creating new directories from the output of something along the lines of

```
cat logs| cut -d',' -f 6 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -10 | \
awk '{print $2}' |xargs mkdir -p
```

Is there a way to create the directories with the sequence number of the argument as processed by xargs as a prefix? For e.g. For e.g. "oranges" is the most frequent entry (of the column) the directory created should be named "1.oranges" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick (and dirty?) solution could be to pipe your directory names through `cat -n` in their proper order and then remove the whitespace separating the line number from the directory name, before passing them to `xargs`.

A better solution would be to modify your `awk` command:

```
... | awk '{ print NR "." $2 }' | xargs mkdir -p
```

The `NR` variable contains the record (i.e. line) number.